# Memory Error while trying to calculate np.zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.68 TiB for an array with shape (120000, 20, 95932) and data type float64
and this is the line that is causing the problem : 
`outs = np.zeros((context_1.shape[0], maxLen, vocab_size))`

is there a workaround for this error?

Comment: Yes, try to create a small array!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create very large array. That's way too much data to store in memory. You should redesign your algorithm, may be use generators to reduce memory requirements.